# Understanding the logic of R code

Tags: r

I am learning R through tutorials, but I have difficulties in "how to read" R code, which in turn makes it difficult to write R code. For example:

```
dir.create(file.path("testdir2","testdir3"), recursive = TRUE)
```

vs

```
dup.names <- as.character(data.combined[which(duplicated(as.character(data.combined$name))), "name"])
```

While I know what these lines of code do, I cannot read or interpret the logic of each line of code. Whether I read left to right or right to left. What strategies should I use when reading/writing R code?

Comment: Read it from the innermost parenthesis, bracket or function towards the outermost.

Answer (score 5):

**`dup.names <- as.character(data.combined[which(duplicated(as.character(data.combined$name))), "name"])`**

## Don't let lines of code like this ruin writing R code for you

I'm going to be honest here. The code is bad. And for many reasons.
Not a lot of people can read a line like this and intuitively know what the output is.
The point is **you should not write lines of code that you don't understand**. This is not Excel, you do not have but 1 single line to fit everything within. You have a whole deliciously large script, an empty canvas. Use that space to break your code into smaller bits that make a beautiful mosaic piece of art! Let's dive in~

## Dissecting the code: Data Frames

Reading a line of code is like looking at a face for familiar features. You can read left to right, middle to out, whatever -- as long as you can lock onto something that is familiar.

Okay you see `data.combined`. You know (hope) it has rows and columns... because it's data!

You spot a `$` in the code and you *know* it has to be a data.frame. This is because only lists and data.frames (which are really just lists) allow you to subset columns using `$` followed by the column name. **Subset**-by the way- just means looking at a portion of the overall. In R, subsetting for data.frames and matrices can be done using single brackets`[`, within which you will see `[row, column]`. Thus if we type `data.combined[1,2]`, it would give you the value in row 1 of column 2.

Now, if you knew that the name of column 2 was `name` you can use `data.combined[1,"name"]` to get the same output as `data.combined$name[1]`. Look back at that code:

**`dup.names <- as.character(data.combined[which(duplicated(as.character(data.combined$name))), "name"])`**

Okay, so now we see our eyes should be locked on `data.combined[SOMETHING IS IN HERE?!])` and slowly be picking out `data.combined[ ?ROW? , Oh the "name" column]`. Cool.

## Finding those ROW values!

**`which(duplicated(as.character(data.combined$name)))`**

Anytime you see the `which` function, it is just giving you locations. An example: For the logical vector `a = c(1,2,2,1)`, `which(a == 1)` would give you `1` and `4`, the location of `1`s in `a`.

Now `duplicated` is simple too. `duplicated(a)` (which is just `duplicated(c(1,2,2,1))`) will give you back `FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE`. If we ran `which(duplicated(a))` it would return `3` and `4`. Now here is a secret you will learn. If you have TRUES and FALSES, you don't need to use the `which` function! So maybe `which` was unnessary here. And also `as.character`... since `duplicated` works on numbers and strings.

## What You Should Be Writing

Who am I to tell you how to write code? But here's my take.
Don't mix up ways of subsetting: use EITHER data.frame[,column] or data.frame$column...
The code could have been written a little bit more legibly as:

```
dupes <- duplicated(data.combined$name)
dupe.names <- data.combines$name[dupes]
```

or equally:

```
dupes <- duplicated(data.combined[,"name"])
dupe.names <- data.combined[dupes,"name"]
```

I know this was lengthy but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very informative. 

I am uncertain if you can reply to this thread due to forum rules, so feel free to PM me, but do you have any recommended online resources or books that I should consider purchasing to increase my knowledge of R? I am all for "messing around" and experiential learning, but it is the logic of writing R code that I have difficulties with.

Comment: I can still comment! Books can be boring, when I was starting R I learned really quickly to get the hang of things from a package called "swirl" - you can install and run this in your Rstudio console using `install.packates("swirl")` which downloads the library and then `library(swirl)` to load/run it. You can from there learn how to do a lot of great basics :)

Comment: I am completing Swirl right now :D. In terms of "reading", am  I forcing a square peg in a round hole? (non-computer science background as you can tell)

"Find the duplicates (in terms of binary true/false) in the data frame called "data.combined" under the "name" variable, and store this output in a variable called "dupes". 

"In the data.combined data frame, match the names under the "name" column to the binary output in the "dupes" variable, and store the result In a variable called "dupe.names".

Comment: Not at all. It may seem like you are bending over backwards but this kind of thing is very common.

Comment: Fair enough. Having this "mentalese" makes it easier to translate thought to code.

Comment: As a follow up, it helps to always consider functions as verbs that act on whatever object is inside their parenthesis: Find `duplicated` (binary is the simple output, `which` is for finding the placement of TRUES in a vector- and a vector can be thought of as 1 column or 1 row of output, even though in truth there is no dimension to it) from the `$name` column/variable of `data.combined` and save it (`<-`) as a variable called "`dupes`".

Comment: Get the subset (`[`) of duplicated rows from `data.combined` with `data.combined[dupes,]` where `dupes` represents row placements and the empty area after the `[dupes,       ]` means to return all columns. ----- I hope I didn't confuse you.

Comment: Hmmm. I cannot quite map your second addition to the more compact version of the code.

Comment: What explicitly are you referring to?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. The second part of the code merely returns all the columns and the associated values for the duplicates.

Comment: Yes exactly. Again, just reading the code is not easy when starting. Always try and run the code yourself one line at a time to see the output :)

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to read any code is to break up their components.

```
dup.names <- 
  as.character(
    data.combined[which(
      duplicated(
        as.character(
          data.combined$name
          )
        )
      ), "name"]
    )
```

For each of the functions - those parts with rounded brackets following them e.g. `as.character()` you can learn more about what they do and how they work by typing `?as.character` in the console

Square brackets `[]` are use to subset data frames, which are stored in your environment (the box to the upper right if you're using R within RStudio contains your values as well as any defined functions). In this case, you can tell that `data.combined` is the name that has been given to such a data frame in this example (type `?data.frame` to find out more about data frames).

Comment: Thank you for the help. That is a good technique.

Answer (score 0):

"Unwrapping" long lines of code can be daunting at first. Start by breaking it down into parenthesis , brackets, and commas. Parenthesis directly tacked onto a word indicate a function, and any commas that lie within them (unless they are part of another nested function or bracket) separate arguments which contain parameters that modify the way the function behaves. We can reduce your 2nd line to an outer function `as.character` and its arguments:

```
dup.names <- as.character(argument_1)
```

Just from this, we know that dup.names will be assigned a value with the [data type "character"](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/character.html) off of a single argument.

Two functions in the first line, `file.path()` and `dir.create()`, contain a comma to denote two arguments. Arguments can either be a single value or specified with an equal sign. In this case, the output of file.path happens to perform as argument #1 of `dir.create()`.

```
file.path(argument_1,argument_2)
dir.create(argument_1,argument_2)
```

Brackets are a way of subsetting data frames, with the general notation of dataframe_object[row,column]. Within your second line is a dataframe object, `data.combined`. You know it's a dataframe object because of the brackets directly tacked onto it, and knowing this allows you to  that any functions internal to this are contributing to subsetting this data frame.

```
data.combined[row, column]
```

So from there, we can see that the internal functions within this bracket will produce an output that specifies the rows of `data.combined` that will contribute to the subset, and that only columns with name `"name"` will be selected.

Use the [help function](https://www.r-project.org/help.html) to start to unpack these lines by discovering what each function does, and what it's arguments are.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is much appreciated.